# What's the right way to make digital representations of prints?

Tags: film, printing, scanning

I'm mostly a film-and-paper photographer: I take pictures, process the film and then make prints in the darkroom.  The end-product of what I do is very definitely a bit of paper.

But I'd like to be able to show representations of these prints digitally (ie on the internet...).  I'd be interested in knowing what the best way to do this is, and also how it's done professionally.  I am specifically interested in *digital representations* of the print: things that will be displayed on a screen, not on producing physical copies of it on paper.

Obviously such a representation can never be exact – there's no way of representing things like texture of the paper surface on a screen for instance – but I want to be able to produce digital representations of my work ('my work' being 'prints') which will give people the best idea I can of what the physical object looks like.

There are three obvious approaches:

- scan the neg (I can do this) and then process the digital copy of it in such a way that it looks like the print I would have made;
- take a very careful photograph of the print, controlling white-balance and so on (so I get a good representation of the paper colour), and use that as the image;
- scan the *print* with a flatbed scanner (this is a variation on the previous approach, really).

The first of these is both hard and unappealing: it requires me to do a lot of work I'm not very interested in to reproduce what I already do in the darkroom, and also may or may not do a good job of representing what the print actually looks like.

The second I can do, and it should be reasonably easy.  Keeping the prints flat is the hard bit, but I can mat them if need be.

I can't currently do the third, but I could buy a flatbed scanner if it's clearly the best approach.

I'd be interested in knowing two things.

- What other people do who have the same problem but don't have access to the resources that, for instance, museums &c have?
- How this is done professionally – if museums or galleries, say, want to produce web pages with good images of physical prints, how do they do this?

I appreciate that a lot of the appearance of things is down to screen calibration: I specifically don't want to address that problem: rather I'm interested in how I could make a digital representation of a print which has the best chance of being displayed well on a properly calibrated screen.

Comment: If printing on paper is part of the creative process rather than a technical step (e.g. you apply techniques such as dodge/burn), then scanning the negative would not be representative of the end product.

Comment: @Pete: yes,  it is.  And what I'd do with scanned negs is to try to reproduce that process so the end result looks as like the print as I can make it (that's what I meant by 'a lot of work I'm not very interested in': mucking around in Photoshop or whatever).  Sorry I should have made that clearer.

Comment: I agree with Pete.  You may get it close but it is not  the same. If i want to show what i have done in the darkroom then i scan the print. If i just want to show  the composition and subject mater without showing how the actual paper print looks then i scan the negative. I could never make a digital version of some of the lith prints ( i can rarely make two lith prints in the darkroom that are the same, the chemistry changes from print to print. ) *This really up to the photographer, we can not tell  you what is "the right way"*.

Comment: Why do you want to show them on the internet would be a first question from me to you. To show off / sell the final image? Or to provide a facsimile of what you do / have made?

Comment: What are your goals? There's quite a bit of difference in technique for an image that I'm simply trying to show a likeness to allow people to see what I did in the darkroom vs allow someone to see the texture of the paper in my print. Also, unless you only print at 8x10 and less, option 3 is out. Option 1b would be to photograph the negative instead of scanning.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to most accurately print a physical picture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/108901/how-to-most-accurately-print-a-physical-picture)

Comment: @MichaelC: I don't think it is a duplicate although the original was misworded: I don't want to make prints (or images in a book) which are good representations of my prints, I want to make things which appear on a screen.  The whole 'how do people make photobooks' section in my question was bogus in that respect and I've removed it now.

Comment: @AthomSfere: what I want to do is to show an image which gives people the best chance of appreciating what the physical object looks like.  Obviously it will never be perfect.

Comment: @Hueco: see my comment to AthomSfere: I want to be able to put stuff on the web which gives people a good idea of what the physical objects look like.  And yes, almost all of my prints are bigger than 8x10, so it looks like scanning is not viable.

Comment: @tfb The suggested duplicate question includes going through the process of creating a digital image file from which to print. If you only want a digital image file, everything in that question and its answers is still valid, you just wouldn't use the digital file created to produce any prints.

Comment: @MichaelC: is it the case that a digital file intended for printing should be the same as a digital file intended only for viewing on a screen? That's surprising to me given the very different characteristics of printed media and screens, but it may be so.

Comment: @tfb In a sense, a digital file can never contain exactly the same information as an analog print. But when the source of a print is a digital image file, the analog print can also not contain any more (meaningful) information than is contained in the digital file. This question more or less states that the digital file should be as accurate a representation as possible of the original print, which is the same assumption made in the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelC: I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but what you are succeeding in doing is making the whole process of asking questions here unpleasant.  It won't let me delete this question, but I'm done here.

Comment: @tfb I don't understand why you seem to be so resistant to the idea that what you are asking here appears to have already been asked and answered within this community. If the creators of the SE network did not desire to mark duplicate questions as such they would not have created the mechanism to do so as a core function of the way the SE networks operate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that you put a significant amount of work in at the darkroom printing stage then scanning the print is the best way to go.  However this can be done either by yourself using a your own scanner or by sending the originals to a company that will scan them to professional standard.  The second option I would only use if the images were to be reproduced in a published book.  A lot of this depends on what the digitized images will be used for - reproduction in a published book, your website, social media sharing, archival purposes.  If the digitized images are only ever going to be viewed on a monitor (ie. they won't be reprinted) then you only need low resolution scans of the original print.  A decent flatbed scanner should easily do the job and it shouldn't cost that much.

Personally I would scan the originals myself except for those few images that will be published in print form in which case I would consider using the services of a company to do the scanning for me.

Comment: So, in particular, do you think scanning is preferable to taking a careful picture (I mean, it *is* taking a picture, but I mean taking a picture with a good digital camera as opposed to with a scanner...)?  That's a good answer if so.

Comment: Yes I definitely think scanning is preferable.  A decent high quality camera will still have to face the difficulties of uneven lighting across the paper and also difficulty in producing consistent results with your different prints.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I've realised that this poses another problem as many of my prints are 12x16.  I'll ask that as another question.

Comment: Be aware though, that many flatbed scanners don't work well with structured paper surfaces (matte, satin, silk). You may have to print on glossy PE paper for that to work.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the second alternative, with some conditions.

I expect your prints to be often larger than A4, and a flatbed this size takes a lot of space, costs money, ...

If you have a wall available, place a vertical flat support on it, buy a piece of "museum glass" (it is basically invisible, no significant reflections, very thin, ...) and place the print between the two.

You can use a good dSLR to take the photo.

A square metre of museum glass costs about 350 Euro, which is about the same as a A3 flatbed scanner, which is smaller.

I'm not sure about flatbed, but the solution I propose allows you to take photos with zero visible reflections.

Comment: I'd like to be able to accept this *and* the scanning one!

Comment: @tfb You asked a question to get an answer that solves your problem... Are your prints up to A3? accept the other one. Are your prints above A3? then the other answer is good but doesn't solve the problem, so choose mine! :)

Comment: Well, this is complicated.  Yes, many are.  But I very often (and perhaps always: I need to check) make smaller prints as preparation for final prints so I don't burn so much paper, and the image area of those is smaller than A4 even (9.5x12 paper, but image area is ~7x10.5 for 35mm).  And a good A4 scanner is cheaper than a good DSLR which I don't own.  So, as I said, it's complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The way major museums and institutions such as the Smithsonian do it is with a large format camera using a digital scan back under very controlled lighting.

[image]

Such a setup combines the strengths of flatbed scanners while scanning at very high resolutions and cameras that give greater control over the lighting used.

More details about such a setup and how it is used can be found at [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/108907/15871) to:

[How to most accurately print a physical picture?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/108901/15871)

If the end goal is a digital image file, then the last step (printing the digital image file at whatever size/quality desired) need not be done.

Comment: This is an interesting answer in the sense of 'if I had huge funds I could do this', so thank you.  Unfortunately I don't have unbounded funds...

Comment: @tfb Youdid ask, "What's the *right* way?' rather than "What's the most cost effective way?" ;-)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant 'right for someone without unlimited means': if I had unlimited means I'd just pay someone to do it and would not be asking.

Comment: Well, you did include in your question, *"How this is done professionally – if museums or galleries, say, want to produce web pages with good images of physical prints, how do they do this?"*

Comment: Depending on how exactly many images you want to digitize, just paying someone to do it might be the most cost effective method.

Answer (score 1):

For your purposes, scanning the print makes sense, as @John Hawthorne explains. However, photographers looking to create a **digital archive** of their film photography should always work with the negative or slide. The original has far more information on it than the print can capture, and a good high resolution scanner will preserve more of the lost detail (though still not as much as in the original).

Excellent information on this is available from the [Library of Congress, like Personal Digital Archiving: The Basics of Scanning](https://blogs.loc.gov/thesignal/2014/03/personal-digital-archiving-the-basics-of-scanning/).

Comment: Yes, completely agree, and this is a useful pointer: thank you.  In so far as I want to make an archive (I often scheme to burn all my negs before I die...) it would be of physical negs I think.